# Почему в CQRS БД разделена на write и read? Зачем?

Tags: база-данных, cqrs

Пытался разобраться сам, читал статьи. Но так и досконально не понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть следующие преимущества:

1. Данные для чтения, как правило, хранятся в виде, удобном для чтения и/или обработки (sic!). Поскольку читатели могут представлять собой совершенно разные (под)системы, то вид данных и места, в которых хранятся данные, могут сильно различаться: это может быть и БД, хранящая денормализованные данные, а может быть и индекс для полнотекстового поиска.
2. При наличии отдельных read и write БД можно легко управлять масштабируемостью. Например, если у вас соотношение read/write = 10/1, то вы без проблем можете добавить нужное количество мощностей к read части, не трогая write часть.

Строго говоря, CQRS содержит требование разделения *операций*. На деле это означает наличие разных моделей данных. Теоретически две (или более) модели могут содержаться в одной БД, но на практике такое или неудобно, или попросту невозможно.

P.S. Хороший вопрос, зачем закрыли?

Answer (score 0):

Так же, благодаря этому разделению пользовательский интерфейс и отчеты меньше влияют на то, как именно построена архитектура предметной области.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?